# Why do I get an error with missing ProtocolStringList in google protobuf?

Tags: java, protoc

I just ran into the problem where a reference to a `ProtocolStringList` caused a class not found error inside the generated code created by protoc.

In this case I got an Eclipse error:

```
com.google.protobuf.ProtocolStringList cannot be resolved to a type
```

I expect it could also show as a:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/protobuf/ProtocolStringList
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I couldn't find an answer to this on Stack Overflow so I'm posting it here.

It turns out this is caused by using later versions of `protoc` (2.6.1 in this case) with older versions of `protobuf-java*.jar`. (2.5.0 in this case).

Comment: could you elaborate? so what you did to resolve the problem? Did a upgrade or downgrade?

Comment: @ThariqNugrohotomo Yep. Just make sure the version of your jar and protoc are the same, you can move either in either direction so long as you run protoc with the same version as the jar you then run the code with.